# Is it correct to use Thread.Join in a non-COM non-GUI app?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winapi, com

.NET's [`Thread.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) documentation says:

> Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates or the specified time elapses, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping.

However, I'm just writing a console app and so the running thread doesn't own a window, and in theory, doesn't have any COM or SendMessage pumping responsibilities - as I understand it.

So, should I really use `Thread.Join()`? Could it come with unwanted overhead?

Comment: Fun fact: If you're running on the full CLR you have a COM apartment in any case. It just doesn't matter. The only thing that text says is that messages will continue to be pumped if you're waiting - you don't have to care about it if you don't need it. Perfectly fine.

Comment: A GUI app is pretty likely to use a COM object, even without you being aware of it.  Drag+drop, shell extensions injected by shell dialogs like OpenFileDialog, the clipboard, UI automation used by another app, controls like WebBrowser.  The [STAThread] attribute on the Main() entrypoint of such an app is crucial, it ensures these features can work correctly, a promise that says that the GUI app uses Application.Run() to solve the producer-consumer problem.  It always does.  None of this applies to a console mode app, it provides the usability of a teletype from the 1970s.